# Angular 4 routing, navigate..multiple redirectTo in child does not support

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm having a problem while routing my app. I tried all possible way that I know but nothing worked for me. It navigates to auth but when children routes added doesn't load anything and yes in auth.component two links are given but none of them is working..

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthComponent} from './auth/auth.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './auth/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent} from './auth/register/register.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './authguard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
  { path: 'auth' , component: AuthComponent,
    children: [ {
      path: '',
      component: LoginComponent},
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent },
    {
      path: 'register',
      component: RegisterComponent},
],
},
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**auth-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthComponent } from './auth.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AuthComponent,
    children: [ {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
},
],
}];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports : [RouterModule],
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

**auth.component.html**

```
<h1>Angular Router</h1>
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>
  <a routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: you have same routes defined in both of your modules? Looks your empty route is going to pages module and will load default route from there. Have you tried localhost:4200/auth ? Do you see any errors in console as I dont see any components declared?

Comment: yes localhost:4200/auth works but only when no children routes. whenever i tried to add them nothing shows up.  And the reason for defining same routes in both modules because  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrap(AppModule) from main.ts...is that wrong??

Comment: auth.component.html links not working??

Comment: I dont know if thats the issue, but you need to have seperate routes for each lazy loaded modules and with forChild() API. App Module can bootstrap and load home component for the app. In that home component, you need to put router outlet with links to different modules. When you click, those route links, respective chunk file will be loaded and then the component routes associated with that module will be rendered. If your feature module is not lazy loaded, you need to import it in app module which I dont see for AuthRoutingModule in your code.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: In app.module, import AuthRoutingModule? If this you're suggesting, then already did that if without import AuthRouthingModule and no auth-route children in app-routing.module,  auth.component.html loaded but when import that nothing loads up . I hope you get what i'm trying to say and sorry my late replies.. it's urgent to be solved

Comment: Not sure about how ur project is set up of App module structure. I think empty route in both the modules causing issue. You may try changing empty route to some named one in one module AppRoutingModule since there, its specified in the end

Answer (score 1):

For child modules routing, you need to use

```
[RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
```

Also,

try importing `AuthRoutingModule` in app module since its not lazy loaded module. The routes from `AuthRoutingModule` are not getting loaded since its a separate module

Comment: Apologies, edit my answer. Did that solve the issue?

Comment: No, still same problem